# Trying to install npm but getting errors

Tags: node.js, npm

What am I doing wrong?

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm install
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\WINDOWS\system32/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\pluci\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-06-02T18_35_04_133Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the -g flag. Ex: `npm install -g npm`

[From the official NPM docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm)

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that you are in the wrong directory.

It is very unlikely that you would want the [`System32`](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/s/system32.htm#:%7E:text=The%20system32%20directory%20contains%20Windows,and%20EXE%20(executable)%20files.) directory for your code, as it contains important Windows system files.

---

To fix this solution, you would most likely need to change your directory using the `cd` command.

Make sure you run the `npm install` command in the correct directory where the `package.json` file exists.

If you don't have a `package.json` file, run the following command to make a `package.json` file, and add your dependencies in there.

```
$ npm init -y
```

Then, you can run the `npm install` command without any errors.

---

In conclusion, the most likely issue with your error is that you are in the wrong directory. You should **never** do your work in a critical OS directory (e.g. `C:\Windows`)!